# How to see the scope of an already winget installed package?

Tags: powershell, winget

How can I see the install *scope* of an already installed package, that has been previously with installed using `winget`?

```
winget install --scope machine -i -e xxxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`winget list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/list) with `--scope machine`, but note that you need to run from an *elevated* session (not necessary for `--scope user`)

```bash
# REQUIRES ELEVATION
winget list --scope machine
```

Comment: This is requiring you to do the list operation for each scope. I was hoping to actually see the scope *somewhere*, from one command. Preferably as an added column to the list command. Or see it in the `winget show`.  I accept this answer, since I don't think it's possible to do this without extensive registry research, but I think this should be an added function to the winget command.

Comment: @not2qubit, I hear you. There's now an alpha version of an [official PowerShell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.WinGet.Client) that wraps `winget`: `Install-Module Microsoft.WinGet.Client -AllowPrerelease` Looks like it's PSv7+ only for now, and also requires you to install the latest `winget.exe` _preview_ version. There's a [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/discussions/3182) to provide feedback on the module.